# Remote Debugging in Visual Studio: Symbol file does not match the module

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging, revit-api

I've been scouring the net trying to find an answer to this question, but all other suggestions don't work.

I have a C# .net 3.5 dll that is an add-in to another program. The program calls the dll when the user presses a certain button. My tool is having an error that is related to the specific setup of the users computer (unrepeatable on mine) so I want to remote debug it.

I have setup debugging tools (2010, but have also tried in VS 2008 for the same result) on the remote PC, and run my DLL. I then go to Debug > Attach to Process, select the remote PC, select the exe 'Revit.exe' that hosts my dll, and it attaches ok. But I can't set any breakpoints or anything as it says there are no symbols loaded. (red unfilled circle with /!)

I open the modules window, right click on my DLL 'PLT2.dll' and try and load the symbols from the symbol path, I select the PDB file which is situated on the network drive right next to the DLL and it says it does not match the module.

I have tried the following based off suggestions I've found on the net:

- Checked that the code is not set to optimize, and that output debug info it set to full.
- PDB file definately matches the DLL, I deleted them all, and rebuilt it.
- The path to symbols on both computers is the same
- Enabled Just My Code

Has anyone got any ideas on what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Could the remote machine be picking up a different version of your binary?

If you remove all the info you added in the Symbols Settings dialog, which path does the modules window show the binaries being loaded from?